# How can I change another user's "About Me" photo?

Tags: login-screen, icons, user-profile

Is there a way for a user with administrative privileges to change another user's "About Me" photo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done by replacing the `.face` file located in the user's home directory with a new photo.
For example, to change the photo for user `bob`:

```
sudo cp new_photo.jpg /home/bob/.face 
sudo chmod 0644 /home/bob/.face 
sudo chown bob /home/bob/.face
```

**NOTE:** Not all image formats will work, so stick to PNG and JPEG.